# How can a consistent drive letter be assigned when mounting a VHD?

Tags: windows-10, vhd

I have several VHDs residing locally, that I only mount one at a time and assign to one drive letter.

How can the drive letter be automatically assigned to these upon mounting, so that I don't have to click "Change Drive Letter" every time I mount?

Typically I mount by using Computer Management -> Storage -> Disk Management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you don't have to do anything on that, because Windows remembers the last drive letter mounted for each VHD drive.

When you change between VHDs (and/or external drives) often, maybe this doesn't work for you.

Of course you can do it with a script. Here is a batch file (without Powershell, which would be more powerful):

[Windows 7 command script to mount VHD disk with assigned drive letter via DiskPart](https://superuser.com/questions/1022894/windows-7-command-script-to-mount-vhd-disk-with-assigned-drive-letter-via-diskpa/1199365#1199365)

For specific VHD files you could simplify that script or just adding fixed names for drive and VHD file. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use Diskpart, you can use PowerShell for this.
Here is an example:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_volume -Filter "DriveLetter = 'F:'" |Set-WmiInstance -Arguments @{DriveLetter='Q:'}
```